# npm 6.3.0 --only=prod install devDependencies also

Tags: npm, npm-install

After upgrading npm version from 5.6.0 to 6.3.0 the `--only=prod` param not works and npm install packages listed in devDependencies also.  But in 5.6.0 version its works as expected. installation proceed without `package-lock.json` in the root folder

node version `8.11.3`
npm version `6.3.0`

I am working on Angular Project. And here is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "frontend-skeleton",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "node build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.1",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.115",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.20",        
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "typescript": "2.9.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.7.1",
    "@angular/cli": "6.1.1",    
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.4",
    "@types/node": "^10.5.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.4.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.5",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.2.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"       
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - running

`NODE_ENV=production npm install`

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

From the [npmjs docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

```
With the --production flag (or when the NODE_ENV environment variable
is set to production),npm will not install modules listed in devDependencies.

NOTE: The --production flag has no particular meaning when adding a dependency
to a project
```

So, use the **NODE_ENV env var** or **--production** flag.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
--only=production
```

or

```
--omit=dev
```